# fourier transform of $f(x) = x^2+\frac{1}{1+2x^4}$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, laplace-transform

I really have no thought on this. I can't seem to use residue thm., nor could I find a inverse transform for it. by some Fourier Calculator I know it's solvable but how?

Comment: f(x), after edit, is not integrable since x^2 is not integrable.

Comment: @Med That's what I thought and I gave up. Ty for letting me know. But Wolfram tells me it's the second derivative of delta function

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier transform of $f(x)$ doesn't exist in the usual sense, but since $f$ can be viewed as a tempered distribution, we can interpret the Fourier transform in that setting. (I'm using the normalization $\hat f(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\omega t}f(t)\,dt$. If you're using something else, the answer is a little different.)

First of all, Fourier transform of $1$ is $2\pi\delta(\omega)$. Hence 
\begin{align*}
 t &\xrightarrow{\mathscr{F}}  2\pi i\delta'(\omega) \\
 t^2 &\xrightarrow{\mathscr{F}}  2\pi i^2\delta''(\omega) = -2\pi\delta''(\omega).
\end{align*}

The second term is less problematic, and exists in the usual sense. It is a standard exercise in residue calculus to compute the Fourier transform of
$\frac{1}{1+2x^4}$. The result (and especially all the intermediate steps) are very messy though. I get:
$$
\hat f(\omega) = -2\pi \delta''(\omega) + 
\begin{cases}
\pi q e^{q\omega} (\cos q\omega - \sin q\omega), & \omega < 0 \\
\pi q e^{-q\omega} (\sin q\omega - \cos q\omega), & \omega \ge 0
\end{cases}
$$
where $q = 2^{1/4}/2$.